# Should I worry about high cached memory?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, caching, memory

I have a problem on one of my linux machines.

I have a node.js application running there and I see that the memory is rising. Further investigation using `free -t` taught me that it's the cached memory that is rising while the buffers memory is pretty stable.

Using `top` or any other tool that shows memory consumption per process doesn't show me any processes that take so much memory.

Should I be worried that the cached memory keeps going up?
Is there a way to reduce the cached memory? Is it problematic to do that?

Any help on that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Cache is used to speed up the application processing time. You don't need to worry about the rising memory as it is taken care by garbage collector. When memory is reached at particular point, garbage collector free up the memory by removing the least used tasks, processes or data and hence you will never run out of memory.

Comment: Yeah but in my case it fills up the entire RAM before it's collected. It slowly goes up to 8GB and then drops to ~6GB and then slowly goes up again. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your node js application is utilizing all the available memory. you should use some profiling tool to spot the code that is consuming memory. You should also practice proper disposing of objects after use that will free up the memory.

Comment: So actually when I check Node's memory usage it's steady. And still the 'cached' memory on the system is rising.